# Flagging problems

Tags: discussion, flagging, specific-flag

I've flagged two question which were closed, but both flags were declined. The questions and the moderator answers are:

[Please help me understand, what is sweet: X or sugar [closed]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401107/please-help-me-understand-what-is-sweet-x-or-sugar)

*declined - Since you do not have enough reputation to vote to close, you should comment so that those who do can vote.*

[why is variance so famous that it appears in almost half of the probability textbook? [closed]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373950/why-is-variance-so-famous-that-it-appears-in-almost-half-of-the-probability-text)

*declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention*

I've done the same practice in Physics SE and my flags were always accepted, this makes me infer that in M.SE the policy is different.

Could someone explain me this?

Comment: I don't understand what was the point of the second flag, really. You seem to have thought the question to be superfluous, and a moderator (correctly) decided that that was not something moderators should be acting upon.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Those flags go into the queue for 10k users and can also put a question into the close review queue. Even if you don't think that moderators should act on them, you don't have to decline them and can let the community handle them. Though I really don't see why a moderator would have to refrain from acting in the first case, that is such a clear off-topic case.

Comment: @MadScientist: yes, I was bad. The message said "Moderator Message" and so I thought that only moderators would see it. I have been informed otherwise :-)

Comment: What exactly is the motivation for flagging two of the most incomprehensible questions of the past month for reopening?

Comment: @Martin Who wants to reopen them?

Comment: My question is: Why did you flag them? What did you want to achieve with those flags?

Comment: @Martin They weren't appropiate to this site and they should be closed.

Answer (score 10):

The problem was a green moderator. I saw the flag listed as "Moderator Message" and thought that only the moderators would see that flag. Now I have been informed that *all* non-custom flags are listed as "Moderator Message". Doh! Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

The general policy (of course, how it is applied in specific instances by individual moderators may vary) is outlined in [Capture the Flag: FAQ on Flagging](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4328/capture-the-flag-faq-on-flagging). As with [Mariano's comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9693/flagging-problems?noredirect=1#comment35535_9693), I agree that the second flag is handled appropriately. We have just [discussed the handling of the first flag](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9693/flagging-problems?noredirect=1#comment35537_9693) in the Mod Chatroom.